A regex to split SQL code into multiple batches
We have a Java program that's used to feed arbitrary SQL code to SQL Servers via JDBC.
The older versions would simply split the input SQL on the ;-character sending one part at a time using JDBC's PreparedStatement.
That was a too simple-minded -- what if the ; is encountered inside a string-literal? -- so the new code tried to throw the entire SQL at the server in one PreparedStatement.
That worked for much of our existing SQL files, except for those, which create stored-procedures and execute them:
INSERT INTO #MEOW VALUES('foo', 1);
INSERT INTO #MEOW VALUES('bar', 2);
CREATE PROCEDURE #MEOW_sp
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT BAR, FOO INTO #WOOF FROM #MEOW
    END;
INSERT INTO #MEOW VALUES('boo', 11);
exec #MEOW_sp;

According to SQL Server documentation, the CREATE PROCEDURE must be the sole statement in a batch.
So we still need to be splitting the SQL blobs, but I'd like a more sophisticated split-boundary than ;. What would the pattern be, that would turn the above SQL code into three parts:

One with the two INSERTs.
One with the CREATE PROCEDURE.
One with the third INSERT and exec.

I imagine, it'd have to use "look-ahead" regex, something like (?=(((CREATE|ALTER)\\s+PROCEDURE[^;]+;*))) -- but it is not working...

With regexes, this is never going to happen. Regexes are not meant to parse programming languages.

@TT, agreed. But I need to get this particular use-case to work... It does not have to be a bullet-proof generic.

Well, for starters, the SQL script you posted is broken. As you said, a create statement has to be the sole statement in a script. So: make sure the script can be executed in one go, and have the create statement in dynamic SQL then execute that SQL.

Yes, that's why I need to split it into three parts -- so that the CREATE PROCEDURE part is in a batch of its own.

Must the solution use regular expressions? If you are open to alternative solutions, then [edit] your question and show how your Java program acquires and processes the SQL. If you can process the SQL line by line, then obviously you identify the start of a stored procedure by CREATE PROCEDURE and the end of a stored procedure by END;.

It would've been easiest to use java.util.regex.Pattern to split the SQL-blob -- and loop over the parts returned by the split.

@MikhailT. And what I'm saying is, fix the script. That'll be one less problem to worry about. See here.

Assuming procedures end with END;:
var batches = s.split(";\\R(?=CREATE)|(?<= END);\\R");


Creating stored procedures definitely don't need to end with END in SQL Server. You might even encounter an END ending another BEGIN/END clause. Any solution with regexes will result in problems, and you'll be lucky the SQL you get out of this fails. Though you will only know once you execute it.

Are you sure that only one END can be in sql statement? Parsing sql by regexp should be started with reading this.

@TT. is correct, that ending with END is not necessary for MS SQL. But that is, how all of our stored-procedures end -- with END; (note the semicolon after that final end). Perhaps, our earlier programmers started with Pascal :-)  I'll test this suggestion right away...

I added the slightly modified (?<=END)[\\s]*;[;\\s]+, and it now works! (We build with encoding US-ASCII, so the \R does not work.) The pattern is compiled with MULTILINE and CASE_INSENSITIVE.

This problem usually solved by using separator that unlikely be a part of SQL code.
I suggest -----.

The existing body of SQL-files is substantial -- if we're to modify them at all, we could as well get rid of these stored procedures and call the inner code in them directly...
